# Parsing Input From User in text_field To Model, Then Display A View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are the exact steps I am trying to take in order to parse data from an API call:

User inputs zip code into text_field, hits submit_tag button
Calls to wunderground API for hourly forecast
Store data from API call to be parsed, maybe in an instance variable...?
Depending on the parsed weather it will display one of two pages (Hot or Cold)

One problem, I either have no idea what I am doing here, or it is so trivial I am over complicating the entire process. (I tend to do that a lot)

What steps would you take in order to complete this task?
I am completely lost and have scoured the internet trying to find an answer for the past week, please help?
Thanks for looking!

Comment: why are you sending it to the controller? are you saving the zip code into the database?

Comment: Sorry I meant model. No, I don't want to store the zip code. I simply just want to parse the API call after the user hits the submit button to either redirect to one of the two pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can have something like this in model so you don't need to save it in database

```
class Foo << ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :zipcode
  attr_accessible :zipcode

 def process_zipcode
   ## make api call and get data
 end
```

end

here you don't need to save zipcode in database.

Comment: First off, sorry about the late response I got caught up with some stuff yesterday. Secondly, so how would I go about creating the correct view for this? Thanks for your help!